# Mock up a method with ref parameter to return specific value

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am using Moq on my .NET Project for Unit Testing my code and
I am trying to mock one of my services which has method with *ref* parameter and return a specific result.

Service code:

```
public bool CallServiceFunctionTest(IList<TestObject> test, ref IList<TestObjectErrors> errors)
{
    //...
    return !errors.Any();
}
```

Controller code:

```
var test = _dataUnitOfWork.TestRepository.GetTest(id);
IList<TestObjectErrors> errors = new List<TestObjectErrors>();
var testingResponse = service.CallServiceFunctionTest(test, errors);
```

TestController code:

```
IList<TestObject> fakeObjects = new List<TestObject>()
{
    new TestObject(){Id = 1 , Name = 'Test'}
};

_dataUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.TestRepository.GetTest(1, null)).Returns(Task.FromResult(fakeObjects));
IList<TestObjectErrors> errors = new It.IsAny<IList<TestObjectErrors>>();
_service.Setup(x => x.CallServiceFunctionTest(fakeObjects, ref errors)).Returns(true);
```

And also tried with same instances as the real call because of the GitHub moq page:

```
IList<TestObjectErrors> errors = new List<TestObjectErrors>();
_service.Setup(x => x.CallServiceFunctionTest(fakeObjects, ref errors)).Returns(true);
```

I read some solutions and try with a callback, without specific parameters but I still don't get the 'true' result.I am sure that I am missing something but I don't know what.I tried also the solution in the moq page in GitHub but without result, here is the ref = > [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Do you really need to be using `ref` in the first place? If you're not explicitly setting the variable to a new list `errors = new List... ` inside the method then it shouldn't be needed. In other words since you're passing a reference type,  changes other than reassignment (add/remove) would be seen by the caller anyways

Comment: The method with the ref parameter is used in a lot of places and I don't want to change all this logic just because of a unit test , so I want to solve that problem properly.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? What's the expected result and what you are getting instead?

Comment: I am trying to mock the result as value = true but I always get the false result.So I want to be able to manage the return result to reproduce all the cases.I am missing something in my setup scope but I don't know what and I tried all I found in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock returning false could be an indication that the arguments set up on the mock do not match what was actually passed while exercising the test.

Loosen the expectations of the mock service with `It.IsAny<T>()` and `It.Ref<T>.IsAny` argument matchers

```
_service
    .Setup(_ => _.CallServiceFunctionTest(It.IsAny<IList<TestObject>>(), ref It.Ref<IList<TestObjectErrors>>.Any))
    .Returns(true);
```

Note that `It.Ref<T>.IsAny` requires Moq 4.8 or later

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Matching Arguments](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)

For older versions, tt should be noted from the linked documentation example

```
// ref arguments
var instance = new Bar();
// Only matches if the ref argument to the invocation is the same instance
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Submit(ref instance)).Returns(true);
```

The ref will only match if the actual instances used while exercising the test are the same.

But in the controller code shown in the example, you are newing up the errors which would mean that the instance in the test would be different to what is being arranged on the mock.

So it looks like older version of Moq is unable to provide the desired behavior without some modification of the code under test

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nkosi. I am aware of that solution but I try to solve it for lower version of Moq ( 4.2 ). If it's possible ofcourse.

Comment: For the lower versions the instances need to be the same. As stated in the doc